# How to encode and decode Base64 and Base64Url in Flutter / Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, base64, base64url

I want to encode the following string in Base64Url in Flutter and decode it in on a Dart server.

```
"username:password"
```

How do I do that? And how do I do it in Base64?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass basic auth credentials in API call for a Flutter mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244416/how-to-pass-basic-auth-credentials-in-api-call-for-a-flutter-mobile-application)

Comment: Also related [How to native convert string -> base64 and base64 -> string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755421/how-to-native-convert-string-base64-and-base64-string)

Comment: I would like to include Base64Url since sometimes it is a requirement. The linked questions, while useful, don't ask or answer that.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `dart:convert` library contains an encoder and decoder for Base64 and Base64Url. However, they encode and decode Lists of integers, so for strings you also need to encode and decode in UTF-8. Rather than doing these two encodings separately, you can combine them with [`fuse`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-convert/Codec/fuse.html).

You need to have the following import:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

### Base64

```
String credentials = "username:password";
Codec<String, String> stringToBase64 = utf8.fuse(base64);
String encoded = stringToBase64.encode(credentials);      // dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
String decoded = stringToBase64.decode(encoded);          // username:password
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
String encoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(credentials)); // dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
String decoded = utf8.decode(base64.decode(encoded));     // username:password
```

### Base64Url

```
String credentials = "username:password";
Codec<String, String> stringToBase64Url = utf8.fuse(base64Url);
String encoded = stringToBase64Url.encode(credentials);      // dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
String decoded = stringToBase64Url.decode(encoded);          // username:password
```

Again, this is equivalent to:

```
String encoded = base64Url.encode(utf8.encode(credentials)); // dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
String decoded = utf8.decode(base64Url.decode(encoded));     // username:password
```

### Notes

- Base64 is encoding, not compression. It won't make your string shorter.
- Base64 is encoding, not encryption. Anyone can decode and read it. Don't send private data over an open network even if it is encoded in Base64.

### See also

- [RCF 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)
- [String based data encoding: Base64 vs Base64url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389211/string-based-data-encoding-base64-vs-base64url)

Comment: instead of constructs like `utf8.decode(base64.decode(credentials));` use `Codec::fuse()` method

Comment: @pskink, At first I couldn't wrap my mind around what was happening (the expanded form felt more readable), but then I realized that you didn't need to switch the order of `utf8` and `base64`. You just use `decode` on the fused method. So, yes, much easier.

Comment: this is because `fuse()` method docs say: *"When encoding, the resulting codec encodes with `this` before encoding with `other`.

When decoding, the resulting codec decodes with `other` before decoding with `this`."*

Comment: btw fuse is not limited to two codecs - you can call multiple fuse methods to chain more than two codecs

Comment: @pskink I also found this one: `Base64Encoder().convert(credentials.codeUnits)`, where you can also do  `Base64Encoder.urlSafe()`. What are your thoughts on this? It seems more readable to me.

Comment: this is [Base64Codec.encoder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Base64Codec/encoder.html) - the same like `base64.encoder`

Comment: is there a way to short the encoded String to only 8 characters?

Comment: @carrasc0, Base 64 is only encoding. It isn't compression. If you want to make the encoded string shorter, then you need to limit the amount of information that you are encoding.

Comment: @Suragch what im trying to do is simple:

In dart, take a string of an ObjectId make it half it size for external urls and then decoded in the app when the link is used. I want this to avoid to make the ids of my items public, but not idea how to make it so far, do you have any?

Comment: @carrasc0, Base 64 also doesn't encrypt anything, so encoding something in Base 64 doesn't make it any less public. Anyone can decode it. As for your question, it is probably better to ask a new Stack Overflow question. But maybe you could use one of the short uuid packages like [nanoid2](https://pub.dev/packages/nanoid2) and then use a lookup table somewhere if you don't want to expose your internal ID.