# How can I encode strings in Flutter Application?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I have a class called ُCreatorUrl in flutter. In this class and other classes, strings including the names of database tables are specified.
How to protect data and strings in the flutter?
Is this a common way of programming?
Please help me.thank's

```
class CreatorUrl {
  static Future<String> createLinkRequest(Map body,{int page:20}) async {
    String blankUrl = 'http:mysite/myApi/api.php?x={"ApiKey":"SAZUChQJh8D7WRyJTc4BERedWd"';
    switch (body['MOD']) {
      case 'select':
        blankUrl=blankUrl+',"MOD":"select","table":"${body['table']}","what":"*","sql":"${body['sql']}","limit":"0,${page==null?200:page}"}';
        break;
      case 'insert':
        blankUrl=blankUrl+',"MOD":"insert","table":"${body['table']}","insert":"${body['insert']}"}';
        break;
      case 'delete':
        break;
      case 'update':
        blankUrl=blankUrl+',"MOD":"update","table":"${body['table']}","update":"${body['update']}","sql":"${body['sql']}"}';
        break;
      case 'count':
        blankUrl=blankUrl+',"MOD":"count","table":"${body['table']}","sql":"${body['sql']}"}';
        break;
      case 'sms':
        blankUrl=blankUrl+',"MOD":"sms","mob":"${body['mob']}","text":"${body['text']}"}';
        print("Im here s");
        break;
    }
    return blankUrl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This may be useful about your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201074/how-to-encode-and-decode-base64-and-base64url-in-flutter-dart)

[Also read this document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Encoding-class.html)