# How to get base64 of a file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, base64, docx, flutter-file

I have an file path string like

```
path = /data/user/0/com.digitalpathshalabd.school/cache/Shaiful_Islam.docx
```

now I want to convert the file into base64

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201075/7924565 check this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode and decode Base64 and Base64Url in Flutter / Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201074/how-to-encode-and-decode-base64-and-base64url-in-flutter-dart)

Comment: thank you all now i am going to implementing yours suggested solutions and i will notify you soon. thank you.

Comment: @ajay  I said I have a file path not image. but you guys provided me a link of how to convert image to base 64 how dose it will work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I come up with a solution.
The thing is we have to get the actual file from path before converting it.

1. get the actual file
2. convert the file into byte array
3. finaly convert the byte array to base64

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class FileConverter {
  static String getBase64FormateFile(String path) {
    File file = File(path);
    print('File is = ' + file.toString());
    List<int> fileInByte = file.readAsBytesSync();
    String fileInBase64 = base64Encode(fileInByte);
    return fileInBase64;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to make it work on flutter web, pal? There, I get this error:

Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace

Comment: could you provide a detailed error message? it will be helpful to figure it out.

Comment: My mistake. In flutter web html.File must be used, no io.File